# GCP Ops agent add static field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ops-agent

I'm trying to add a static value field to the ops agent without success. This is the processor I'm using:

```
modify_fields:
  type: modify_fields
  fields:
    env:
      static_value: somenv
```

Also tried:

```
modify_fields:
  type: modify_fields
  fields:
    env:
      default_value: somenv
```

I just need all the documents sent by that machine to have a "env" field with value "someenv"

The error I'm getting is "env field not found"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was this feature was not available in the version I was using (2.16), so I upgraded to 2.18 and now works.

Also, need to follow the [LogEntry](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry) structure

```yaml
modify_fields:
  type: modify_fields
  fields:
    jsonPayload.env:
      static_value: somenv
```

Also `record_log_file_path` property which wasn't working is working now.